# Performance of R stats::sd() vs. arma::stddev() vs. Rcpp implementation

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp, armadillo

Just for the purpose of working on my C++ / Rcpp programming, I took a shot at implementing a (sample) standard deviation function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double cppSD(Rcpp::NumericVector rinVec)
{
  std::vector<double> inVec(rinVec.begin(),rinVec.end());
  int n = inVec.size();
  double sum = std::accumulate(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), 0.0);
  double mean = sum / inVec.size();

  for(std::vector<double>::iterator iter = inVec.begin();
      iter != inVec.end(); ++iter){
        double temp;
        temp= (*iter - mean)*(*iter - mean);
        *iter = temp;
      }

  double sd = std::accumulate(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), 0.0);
  return std::sqrt( sd / (n-1) );
}
```

I also decided to test out the `stddev` function from the Armadillo library, considering that it can be called on a vector:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double armaSD(arma::colvec inVec)
{
  return arma::stddev(inVec);
}
```

Then I benchmarked these two functions against the base R function `sd()` for a few vectors of varying size:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('G:/CPP/armaSD.cpp')
Rcpp::sourceCpp('G:/CPP/cppSD.cpp')
require(microbenchmark)
##
## sample size = 1,000: armaSD() < cppSD() < sd()
X <- rexp(1000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X),sd(X), cppSD(X)) 
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
# armaSD(X)  4.181  4.562  4.942  5.322 12.924   100
#     sd(X) 17.865 19.766 20.526 21.287 86.285   100
#  cppSD(X)  4.561  4.941  5.321  5.701 29.269   100
##
## sample size = 10,000: armaSD() < cppSD() < sd()
X <- rexp(10000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X),sd(X), cppSD(X))
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr    min     lq  median      uq     max neval
# armaSD(X) 24.707 25.847 26.4175 29.6490  52.455   100
#     sd(X) 51.315 54.356 55.8760 61.1980 100.730   100
#  cppSD(X) 26.608 28.128 28.8885 31.7395 114.413   100
##
## sample size = 25,000: armaSD() < cppSD() < sd()
X <- rexp(25000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X),sd(X), cppSD(X))
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq  median      uq     max neval
# armaSD(X)  66.900  67.6600  68.040  76.403 155.845   100
#     sd(X) 108.332 111.5625 122.016 125.817 169.910   100
#  cppSD(X)  70.320  71.0805  74.692  80.203 102.250   100
##
## sample size = 50,000: cppSD() < sd() < armaSD()
X <- rexp(50000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X),sd(X), cppSD(X))
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq   median      uq     max neval
# armaSD(X) 249.733 267.4085 297.8175 337.729 642.388   100
#     sd(X) 203.740 229.3975 240.2300 260.186 303.709   100
#  cppSD(X) 162.308 185.1140 239.6600 256.575 290.405   100
##
## sample size = 75,000: sd() < cppSD() < armaSD()
X <- rexp(75000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X),sd(X), cppSD(X))
#Unit: microseconds
#      expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
# armaSD(X) 445.110 479.8900 502.5070 520.5625 642.388   100
#     sd(X) 310.931 334.8780 354.0735 379.7310 429.146   100
#  cppSD(X) 346.661 380.8715 400.6370 424.0140 501.747   100
```

I was not terribly surprised at the fact that my C++ function `cppSD()` was faster than `stats::sd()` for smaller samples, but slower for larger sized vectors since `stats::sd()` is vectorized. However, I did not expect to see such a performance degradation from the `arma::stddev()` function since it appears to also be operating in a vectorized manner. Is there a problem with the way that I'm using `arma::stdev()`, or is it simply that `stats::sd()` was written (in `C` I'm assuming) in such a way that it can handle larger vectors much more efficiently? Any input would be appreciated.

---

**Update**:

Although my question was originally about the correct use of `arma::stddev`, and not so much about trying find the most efficient way possible to calculate the sample standard deviation, it is very interesting to see that the `Rcpp::sd` sugar function performs so well. To make things a little more interesting, I benchmarked the `arma::stddev` and `Rcpp::sd` functions below against an `RcppParallel` version that I adapted from two of JJ Allaire's Rcpp Gallery posts - [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-vector-sum/) and [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-inner-product/):

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(5.5e06)
##
Res <- microbenchmark(
  armaSD(x),
  par_sd(x),
  sd_sugar(x),
  times=500L,
  control=list(warmup=25))
##
R> print(Res)
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   armaSD(x) 24.486943 24.960966 26.994684 25.255584 25.874139 123.55804   500
   par_sd(x)  8.130751  8.322682  9.136323  8.429887  8.624072  22.77712   500
 sd_sugar(x) 13.713366 13.984638 14.628911 14.156142 14.401138  32.81684   500
```

This was on my laptop running 64-bit linux with a i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz processor; but I'm guessing the difference between `par_sd` and `sugar_sd` would be less substantial on a Windows machine.

And the code for the `RcppParallel` version (which is considerably longer, and requires a C++11 compatible compiler for the lambda expression used in overloaded `operator()` of the `InnerProduct` functor):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

/*  
 * based on: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-vector-sum/
 */
struct Sum : public RcppParallel::Worker {

  const RcppParallel::RVector<double> input;
  double value;

  Sum(const Rcpp::NumericVector input)
  : input(input), value(0) {}
  Sum(const Sum& sum, RcppParallel::Split)
  : input(sum.input), value(0) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    value += std::accumulate(input.begin() + begin,
                             input.begin() + end,
                             0.0);
  }

  void join(const Sum& rhs) {
    value += rhs.value;
  }

};

/*
 * based on: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-inner-product/
 */
struct InnerProduct : public RcppParallel::Worker {

  const RcppParallel::RVector<double> x;
  const RcppParallel::RVector<double> y;
  double mean;
  double product;

  InnerProduct(const Rcpp::NumericVector x,
               const Rcpp::NumericVector y,
               const double mean)
  : x(x), y(y), mean(mean), product(0) {}

  InnerProduct(const InnerProduct& innerProduct,
               RcppParallel::Split)
  : x(innerProduct.x), y(innerProduct.y),
    mean(innerProduct.mean), product(0) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    product += std::inner_product(x.begin() + begin,
                                  x.begin() + end,
                                  y.begin() + begin,
                                  0.0, std::plus<double>(),
                [&](double lhs, double rhs)->double {
                  return ( (lhs-mean)*(rhs-mean) );
                });
  }

  void join(const InnerProduct& rhs) {
    product += rhs.product;
  }

};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double par_sd(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x_)
{
  int N = x_.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector y_(x_);
  Sum sum(x_);
  RcppParallel::parallelReduce(0, x_.length(), sum);

  double mean = sum.value / N;
  InnerProduct innerProduct(x_, y_, mean);
  RcppParallel::parallelReduce(0, x_.length(), innerProduct);

  return std::sqrt( innerProduct.product / (N-1) );
}
```

Comment: In addition to the issue pointed out by Dirk Eddelbuettel below, your cppSD() function has further problems. It's not a robust way of calculating the standard deviation, as it's easily affected by floating point overflows in the sum variable. std::accumulate() is not designed for numerics. Instead, your code should be using running statistics either as the primary calculation method, or as a fallback. The cppSD() function is also inefficient: it's unnecessarily copying the data to a fresh vector and then re-writing the vector. Instead, it should be using the original data in a read-only manner

Comment: This bears repeating: using functions such as std::accumulate() or std::inner_product() to calculate the mean and standard deviation is a really bad idea: they are not robust to floating point overflows or underflows. Armadillo's standard deviation function is far safer, as it takes these potential issues into account. Using the above parallelization method you're just going to get bad results quicker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You made a subtle mistake in how you instantiate the Armadillo object -- which leads to copies and hence degraded performance.

Use an interface of `const arma::colvec & invec` instead, and all is good:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/sd.cpp")

R> library(microbenchmark)

R> X <- rexp(500)

R> microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X))
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq  median      uq    max neval
  armaSD(X)  3.745  4.0280  4.2055  4.5510 19.375   100
 armaSD2(X)  3.305  3.4925  3.6400  3.9525  5.154   100
      sd(X) 22.463 23.6985 25.1525 26.0055 52.457   100
   cppSD(X)  3.640  3.9495  4.2030  4.8620 13.609   100

R> X <- rexp(5000)

R> microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X))
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq  median      uq    max neval
  armaSD(X) 18.627 18.9120 19.3245 20.2150 34.684   100
 armaSD2(X) 14.583 14.9020 15.1675 15.5775 22.527   100
      sd(X) 54.507 58.8315 59.8615 60.4250 84.857   100
   cppSD(X) 18.585 19.0290 19.3970 20.5160 22.174   100

R> X <- rexp(50000)

R> microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X))
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
  armaSD(X) 186.307 187.180 188.575 191.825 405.775   100
 armaSD2(X) 142.447 142.793 143.207 144.233 155.770   100
      sd(X) 382.857 384.704 385.223 386.075 405.713   100
   cppSD(X) 181.601 181.895 182.279 183.350 194.588   100
R>
```

which is based on my version of your code where everything is one file and `armaSD2` is defined as I suggested -- leading to the winning performance.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]  
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double cppSD(Rcpp::NumericVector rinVec) {
  std::vector<double> inVec(rinVec.begin(),rinVec.end());
  int n = inVec.size();
  double sum = std::accumulate(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), 0.0);
  double mean = sum / inVec.size();

  for(std::vector<double>::iterator iter = inVec.begin();
      iter != inVec.end(); 
      ++iter){
    double temp = (*iter - mean)*(*iter - mean);
    *iter = temp;
  }

  double sd = std::accumulate(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), 0.0);
  return std::sqrt( sd / (n-1) );
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]      
double armaSD(arma::colvec inVec) {
  return arma::stddev(inVec);
}

//  [[Rcpp::export]]    
double armaSD2(const arma::colvec & inVec) { return arma::stddev(inVec); }

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
X <- rexp(500)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X)) 

X <- rexp(5000)
microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X)) 

X <- rexp(50000)    
microbenchmark(armaSD(X), armaSD2(X), sd(X), cppSD(X))
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `sd` function built in Rcpp sugar is much more efficient. See the code below:

```
   #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
   //[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
   #include <vector>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <numeric>
   using namespace Rcpp;
   //[[Rcpp::export]]                                                                                                                                                         
  double sd_cpp(NumericVector& xin){
 std::vector<double> xres(xin.begin(),xin.end());
 int n=xres.size();
 double sum=std::accumulate(xres.begin(),xres.end(),0.0);
 double mean=sum/n;
 for(std::vector<double>::iterator iter=xres.begin();iter!=xres.end();++iter){
   double tmp=(*iter-mean)*(*iter-mean);
   *iter=tmp;
 }
   double sd=std::accumulate(xres.begin(),xres.end(),0.0);
   return std::sqrt(sd/(n-1));
 }
  //[[Rcpp::export]]
 double sd_arma(arma::colvec& xin){
 return arma::stddev(xin);
}
 //[[Rcpp::export]]
 double sd_sugar(NumericVector& xin){
 return sd(xin);
}

> sourcecpp("sd.cpp")

> microbenchmark(sd(X),sd_cpp(X),sd_arma(X),sd_sugar(X))
   Unit: microseconds
      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
      sd(X) 47.655 49.4120 51.88204 50.5395 51.1950 113.643   100
  sd_cpp(X) 28.145 28.4410 29.01541 28.6695 29.4570  37.118   100
  sd_arma(X) 23.706 23.9615 24.65931 24.1955 24.9520  50.375   100
 sd_sugar(X) 19.197 19.478 20.38872 20.0785 21.2015  28.664   100
```

Comment: Using std::accumulate() to calculate the mean and standard deviation is a really bad idea: it's not robust to floating point overflows or underflows. Armadillo's standard deviation function is far safer, as it takes these potential issues into account.

Answer (score 0):

2 questions about the Rcpp function:

1) how likely is it that you would want the standard deviation without the mean? If it will be uncommon to require SD without the mean, why not return both rather than ask the R user to make 2 function calls which in effect calculate the mean twice.

2) Is there any reason for cloning the vector inside the function?

```cpp
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cppSD(NumericVector rinVec)
{
  double n = (double)rinVec.size();
  double sum = 0;
  for (double& v : rinVec)
     sum += v;
  double mean = sum / n;
  double varianceNumerator = 0;
  for(double& v : rinVec)
     varianceNumerator += (v - mean) * (v - mean);
  return NumericVector::create(_["std.dev"] = sqrt(varianceNumerator/ (n - 1.0)),
                               _["mean"] = mean);
}
```